# Как заполнить ячйки типа DataGridViewComboBoxColumn своими значениями?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

Есть `DataGridView`. Структура его - одна колонка типа `TextBox`, вторая `ComboBox`. Я могу заполнить `Items`, но это значения будут для всех ячеек данной колонки.

```
int index = dgvServers.Rows.Add(server.WebServiceUrl, "");
    
var comboColumn = this.dgvServerList.Columns["Profiles"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
foreach (var profile in server.Profiles)
{
    comboColumn.Items.Add(profile);
}
```

Возможно ли, чтобы каждая ячейка `ComboBox` в гриде содержала свой список значений? Я имею ввиду, чтобы построчно я мог пройтиcь по гриду и отделно заполнить `Items` для каждой ячейки? Спасибо все фанатам программизма))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    // Укажите индекс или имя нужной колонки
    var cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[1];

    // Задаём список значений
    cell.Items.AddRange("a" + row.Index, "b" + row.Index, "c" + row.Index);
}
```

Но по-правильному, следует использовать привязку данных и класс-модель.

Comment: спасибо за ответ и совет